# $(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y}_i) = 0$

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, covariance, invariance

$(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y}) = 0$ in the image below (third and fourth line of the proof!). Why?

[image: Correlation between y and y-hat]

Comment: I do agree to the first line. And I cannot comprehend the transforming from third line to the fourth line too.

Answer (score 1):

By $\hat{Y}_i$ you mean the MMSE estimator (or the posterior mean) ?

If so, remember a very important property of this estimator is that the MMSE estimator of $Y$ is that the error $\hat Y - Y$ is orthogonal to any function of $Y$. Thus $E[(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})] = 0$. But in your case there are no expectations. Please verify that or give the full context of this derivation

Comment: I am taking my first course in regression and was trying to see how square of correlation of y and y hats is the r squared value. I got the above picture from: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Pearson.E2.80.99s_distance. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: @Bhrigu Aneja: yes so please see what I wrote. It holds also for the sample covariance which is the approximation of the expectation I wrote above. The error is orthogonal to any function of Y